Can we interpret one compound sentence in multiple ways?
Compound sentence definition:

​​compound sentences combine two or more independent clauses. The key here is independent clauses, which are clauses that can each stand alone as a separate sentence.


Dependent clauses constructed with the subordinating conjunction function as one modification clause similar to that preposition functions as one modification part for the noun:

Subordinating conjunctions and relative pronouns are words like because, if, or whenever that signal a relationship between the dependent clause and the independent clause it joins.

This means that this sentence

Kunal likes to stay up late because no one bothers him at night.

uses "because no one bothers him at night" to describe the former independent clause just like that "in the class" describes "the student" in "the student in the class".

Although independent clauses have just the parallel relationship, this compound sentence having 3 independent clauses can have multiple ways of interpretation:

I I am writing a book, but it still isn't finished, and I doubt it ever will be.

Are this

(I am writing a book, but it still isn't finished), and I doubt it ever will be.

and this

I am writing a book, but (it still isn't finished, and I doubt it ever will be).

both possible?
Then the former means that I doubt the book ever will be written. Although that contradicts a bit with "I am writing a book", it is one fine interpretation without considering the semantic weirdness.
Q:
Are the above 2 ways of interpretation fine? If not, can we interpret one compound sentence in multiple ways for some other example?

Your "definition" of a dependent clause is garbled, to say the least. I'm not sure what function as one modification clause similar to that preposition functions as one modification part for the noun is supposed to mean. But I know that your example sentence I wrote a book last week, but it still isn't finished, and I doubt it ever will be is just nonsense. If you say you wrote the book, that means it's finished, so you can't doubt that it will be finished.

@FumbleFingers Thanks. I have improved my questions just now and added one link forgotten to add. Maybe the "I wrote a book last week" in the link means "... partially".

@An5Drama As suggested by FumbleFingers, please correct your sentences. It should be,  "I am writing a book (no last week) It means you are in the process of writing a book (whenever you get time.) It doesn't imply you are continuously writing a book." I was writing a book last week"means you stopped writing.

@JamesMathai Thanks. Updated now.

Let's rephrase slightly:

I started writing a book last week, but it still isn't finished, and I doubt it ever will be.

The OP is asking whether both

(I started writing a book last week, but it still isn't finished), and I doubt it ever will be.

and

I started writing a book last week, but (it still isn't finished, and I doubt it ever will be).

are possible.
Edit
For the given text, there are no possible different meanings from different placements of parentheses.  The two versions mean the same: I doubt the book will ever be completed.
This example from FumbleFingers can give different meanings depending on the bracketing:

Tom smoked a joint, which is illegal, Dick told me.


Thanks. Is there some example to have different meanings when we use different implicit parentheses for compound sentence like  lisschesci says for preposition in http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-4.45?

There are no possible "different meanings" with your example text. Personally, I don't think it makes sense to think of "imaginary brackets" here either. Perhaps you're thinking of an example context such as Tom smoked a joint, which is illegal, Dick told me, which can be parsed differently. With my example you can have imaginary brackets starting (1) after the first comma, OR (2) after the second comma. The difference being that in parsing 2 it's possible Tom never actually smoked a joint at all (it's just that Dick claimed he did).

Good example, @FumbleFingers.  I've adopted it in my answer.

Oops! Perhaps I should have chosen a more "Safe for Work" example! :)

No worry, illegal is clearly stated.
